# How to resize image when there is less height, while respecting the container below?

Tags: html, css

The img tag resizes automatically.

However, I'm making a lightbox that when you click, the image appears in the middle, and at the bottom you have all images showing.

The bottom bar with images, should be always at the bottom, and the image should be proportionated in the center of the screen, especting the bar at the bottom.

So when we resize the screen from the bottom e.g.  open the dev tools, the image should shrink and the bar at the bottom should go up.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/eKEQMP?editors=0100

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="gallery__list">

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4357/36172707494_53c0f25d98_h_d.jpg">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4357/36172707494_53c0f25d98_h_d.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://ritzcarlton-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/the-ritz-carlton/hotels/asia-pacific/japan/tokyo/guest-rooms/RCTOKYO_00451.jpg?$XlargeViewport100pct$">
        <img src="https://ritzcarlton-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/the-ritz-carlton/hotels/asia-pacific/japan/tokyo/guest-rooms/RCTOKYO_00451.jpg?$XlargeViewport100pct$">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/hd-place-wallpaper-high-definition-cool-images-cities-desktop-images-view-point-hd-Exotic-Places-1920x1200.jpg">
        <img src="https://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/hd-place-wallpaper-high-definition-cool-images-cities-desktop-images-view-point-hd-Exotic-Places-1920x1200.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/landscapes-cool-images-cities-best-place-ever-backgrounds-view-point-world-Exotic-Places-1920x1200-768x480.jpg">
        <img src="https://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/landscapes-cool-images-cities-best-place-ever-backgrounds-view-point-world-Exotic-Places-1920x1200-768x480.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="http://hotelslike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/117725.jpg">
        <img src="http://hotelslike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/117725.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

  <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="https://blog.eurail.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/La-Rambla-at-night.jpg">
        <img src="https://blog.eurail.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/La-Rambla-at-night.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

  <li class="gallery__item">
    <a class="gallery__link" href="http://www.hopper.com/cms-assets/images/Destinations/Europe/Ireland/Dublin_shutterstock_111481523_800x.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.hopper.com/cms-assets/images/Destinations/Europe/Ireland/Dublin_shutterstock_111481523_800x.jpg">
    </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>


<div class="modal-gallery">
<div class="modal-gallery__main">
<div class="modal-gallery__main--outer">

        <!-- Tool Bar -->
        <ul class="modal-gallery__tool-bar">
            <span class="modal-gallery__close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <a class="modal-gallery__downolad" href=""><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <span class="modal-gallery__fullscreen"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <span class="modal-gallery__autoplay"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <div class="modal-gallery__counter">
                <span class="modal-gallery__counter--current">1</span>
          <span>/</span>
                <span class="modal-gallery__counter--all">5</span>
            </div>
        </ul>


    <!-- Main Section -->
        <div class="modal-gallery__main-image-wrap">
        <img class="modal-gallery__main-image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">

        <div class="modal-gallery__arrow-wrap">
            <button class="modal-gallery__arrow-prev"></button>
            <button class="modal-gallery__arrow-next"></button>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-gallery__pic-list">
    <ul class="modal-gallery__pic-list-wrap">

            <li class="modal-gallery__item">
            <a class="modal-gallery__link" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
            </a>
            </li>

      <li class="modal-gallery__item">
            <a class="modal-gallery__link" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
            </a>
            </li>

      <li class="modal-gallery__item">
            <a class="modal-gallery__link" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
            </a>
            </li>

      <li class="modal-gallery__item">
            <a class="modal-gallery__link" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/62/e1/35/62e135d63fef91cdc2d058a8542507d3.jpg">
            </a>
            </li>

    </ul>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  height:  auto;
}

// Gallery List
.gallery {

  &__item {
    width: calc(25%);
    float: left;
    height: 220px;

    & img {
      height: 220px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }



}

// Gallery Modal
.modal-gallery {
     position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease 0s;
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
    // opacity: .95;

  &__main {
      height: auto;
      position: relative;

    &--outer {
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 15px;
    }
  }

  &__main-image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;

  }

  &__main-image {
    width: auto;
    // max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &__arrow-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  &__tool-bar {
    color: #acabab;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  }

  &__counter {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  &__pic-list {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  &__pic-list-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
    border: 1px solid #313131;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &__item {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;

    & img {
       height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap both the slideshow element and the bottom bar with images in a container.
2. Give each one an explicit height (i.e. slideshow `height: 80%`, bottom bar `height: 20%`).
3. Then apply `height: 100%` to the image containers (i.e. `a` and or `li`).
4. Then apply `height: 100%; width: auto;` to each image. This will make the images responsive while maintaining their aspect ratio. However, it's important that the image container is dynamic (i.e. height/width % or vh or w/e). You could also do `width: 100%; height: auto;` for instance.

Comment: The bottom bar needs to be always 175px and not in %, those making the proportions bad if I put 80% on the slideshow. A way to do it this way? As the above way is not going to work if I put 175px.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec in that case, you have two options: (1) you can use JavaScript to achieve responsiveness; or (2) you could use fixed heights instead of flexible heights (i.e. container `height: 500px`, slideshow `height: 325px`, bottom panel `height: 175px`).

Comment: The purpose of this is to be responsive, however, the height of the bar needs to be 175px. 

How would I do that with JS?

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec well, if you give a fixed height to the bottom panel, the bottom panel will not be responsive. first, determine what responsive height you'd like the container to have (i.e. 75%), use JS to figure out the size of the container in pixels, subtract 175px from that and apply the result to the image containers when the document loads and every time the window is resized.

Comment: If you're on a smaller screen like a tablet, and you have only 10% for the pictures in the bar, it's not enough to see them, that's why 175px is better. If it's too much, it will lose proportions of the design. On mobile, you might want to have a percentage. One of the popular adult industry site, with orange logo has a gallery like this, similar, and they did it that way. I didn't see anywhere they used positon absolute etc... I'll try the solution with JS you told me.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec you should easily be able to achieve this if you use JS

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec u figure it out?!

Comment: Well, not really. I'm new to JavaScript and didn't expect to make this, though you can do it in CSS, and my purpose of doing this lightbox is to learn, as I know how to do it ish, but the resize bit is a bit out of what I wanted to do, but I guess that's also good to learn, so the lightbox isn't that bad of an idea :D - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/eKEQMP I did wrote some code as for now but hmmm. Not sure how to check this for resize every second.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec a couple ways to listen for resize events are `window.onresize = () => { your block of code here }` or `window.addEventListener('onresize', NameOfYourFunction)`